# Как мерить трафик?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, браузер, загрузка, трафик

Нужна программа принимающая название браузера и адрес страницы. Необходимо чтобы программа запускала этот адрес и смотрела сколько мегабайт загружается в процессе. Подскажите на чем вообще такое писать и есть ли у этой штуки общепринятое название?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос интересный, но не простой.

Посмотрим на процесс загрузки страницы.

Страница состоит из html, картинок и скриптов. И картинки, и скрипты не только грузятся с внешних ресурсов, но и кешируются. Это означает, что при первом заходе по некоторому адресу и при втором заходе по нему же объем загруженного трафика может сильно различаться.

Кроме того, если какой то скрипт закеширован - это означает, что ДРУГАЯ страница, котрая использует его же (jquery, например) уже не будет его выкачивать.

В то же время в характеристиках сетевого интерфейса, который поазывают такие команды как ifconfig - есть счетчики переданного и принятого трафика.

Рассмотрим такую схему: мы для каждого URL запускаем легковесную виртуальную машину с браузером, у которого очищен кеш. И по окончнии загрузки - например, через условные 30 секунд - спрашиваем у сетевого интерфейса внутри виртуалки, сколько трафика было передано и принято.

Тогда цифра, которую покажет команда ifconfig, будет довольно точно показывать максимальный объем трафика, который понадобился для отображения страницы со всеми вложенными элементами.

Идея Вам понятна?

Как это реализовывать?

Опять таки, не самый простой вопрос. Реализация с настоящей вииртуалкой, которая управляется командой virsh - довольно громоздка. Я бы стал копать в сторону докер - контейнера, внутри которого установлен и запускается браузер. Как из контейнера извлечь нужную инфу - ну, это уже дело техники...

Еще одно направление, в котором можно посмотреть - так называемые headless - браузеры, что то вроде selenium. Это штуки, часто используемые в автоматизированном тестировании. При этом они очень точно повторяют работу обычного браузера. Их headlss-ность ("безголовость", отсутствие графического интерфейса) может дать существенную экономию.

Ну и, конечно, возможно - я не совсем правильно или как то слишком однобоко понял вопрос - тогда поправьте меня...

PS после комментария с уточнением вопроса.

Грубо говоря, если при загрузке страницы нажать f12  и зайти на вкладку network браузера - там будут перечислены все загружаемые страницей элементы и их размер. [Сложить эти размеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239980/measure-full-page-size-in-chrome-devtools) - и будет нужный автору вопроса результат.

Но как бы это автоматизировать?

Кажется, я нашел [расширение для хрома](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-source-viewer/cfmcghennfbpmhemnnfjhkdmnbidpanb), которое делает что то такое. Вот что про него пишут: "Displays HTML, Javascript and CSS sources of a page in a fast and compact way".

Расширения дяя хрома имеют описанный формат. его можно "расковырять" и посмотреть, как там всё считается.

Также, есть [еще](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-size-inspector/oepnndnpjiahgkljgbohnnccmokgcoln) проект на эту тему.

Comment: А если вдруг надо сделать аналогичное из javascript? То есть пользователь сайта открывает у себя страницу и скрипт на ней выводит ему сколько у него ушло мегабайт конкретно на загрузку этой страницы (а не у всего браузера в течении этой загрузки)? Есть такая функция/фреймворк?

Comment: я такой функции не знаю. Проблема состоит в том, что когда браузер не работает в изолированном окружении (в виртуальной машине) - в нём могут прараллельно работать многие вкладки, каждая из которых использует общий канал связи. Поэтому полагаться на измеренное системой - нельзя. Может быть, есть какие то низкоуровневые инструменты, встроенные в сам браузер?

Comment: я дополнил ответ, посмотрите при случае